# Use Wufoo API fields in custom HTML Code

Tags: php, jquery, wufoo

I need to use the Wufoo API, to get the field information and submit it back to Wufoo but I need to be able to build my own custom HTML - so it looks different.

Any ideas or examples, I've read loads of documentation on this but could do with seeing an example.

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just pulled the form up in a lightbox, not as I wanted it but looked ok in the end.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to dynamically create the HTML using the Fields API?  If so, follow these steps:

1) Pull the fields using the [Fields API](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/fields/)

2) Create a template for each Field Type.  Be sure to set the name attribute of your form fields equal to the ID provided by the API

3) As you move through your fields, in the API, output your field templates.

Some things to be aware of:

- We don't currently return the Section Breaks, so faithfully recreating every form is not possible.  We're looking to the breaks soon, but have not done so yet.
- If you're looking for static, pre-made HTML, you can use the HTML/CSS provided by the [Code Manager](http://wufoo.com/docs/code-manager/#ctbcs) as a template and move from there.
- If you create your own form, you'll need to use the [Entries POST API](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/entries/post/) to submit the data to the appropriate user's account.

EDIT: Code examples live here: [link text](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/examples/)

Comment: Hi,Yes I'm trying to do it dynamically... I'd read that info on the API, but I was just also seeing if anybody had any code to offer for once I've recieved the xml back from the API rather than writing something fresh, if that makes sense? Or am I just being lazy :-)